# Local bash variables in terraform tpl

Tags: bash, terraform

I want to assume role then save its output in a variable and then use that variable to extract some credentials from it. But terraform is throwing an error.

```
#!/bin/sh

ASSUME_ROLE=$(aws sts assume-role --output json --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123123123123:role/SomeRole --role-session-name test --profile myprofile)

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo ${ASSUME_ROLE} | awk -F'"' '/AccessKeyId/{print $4}')
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo ${ASSUME_ROLE} | awk -F'"' '/SecretAccessKey/{print $4}')
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo ${ASSUME_ROLE} | awk -F'"' '/SessionToken/{print $4}')

aws --profile myprofile route53 create-vpc-association-authorization --hosted-zone-id abcd3245 --vpc VPCRegion=us-east-1,VPCId=vpc-123e123

aws route53 associate-vpc-with-hosted-zone --hosted-zone-id abcd3245 --vpc VPCRegion=us-east-1,VPCId=vpc-123e123
```

Here is the output

```
There is no variable named "ASSUME_ROLE"., and 2 other diagnostic(s)
```

Comment: Having `#!/bin/sh` makes this not a Bash script. Either make sure you don't use any Bash-only constructs, or change the shebang to point to `bash` instead of `sh`. See also [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: I have ran and tested this script in a separate sh file and it was working. But when I added it into my terraform code it always shows the same error. @tripleee

Comment: terraform fail assigning value to bash variable, here is the way u might intrested `resource "null_resource" "ec2-des" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    on_failure  = "fail"
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    command     = <<EOT
        echo -e "\x1B[31m loading.................. \x1B[0m"
        aws ec2 describe-addresses --profile test >> info.txt
        cat info.txt | awk '{print $1}' #what ever
    EOT
  }
  triggers = {
     always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
}`

Answer (score 2):

This error indicates that Terraform's `template_file` implementation understood `${ASSUME_ROLE}` as being a template interpolation and so it tried to find an element named `ASSUME_ROLE` in the template `vars` map.

It doesn't seem like there are any actual Terraform template sequences in this string, in which case there's no reason to render this as a template. Instead, just read it verbatim using [the `file` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/file.html).

If you *do* need this to be a template, you can escape the literal `${` sequences by writing `$${` instead. Terraform's template language replaces `$${` with `${` during rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to export your `ASSUME_ROLE` variable. `export` makes variables available in subshells (and `$(echo ${ASSUME_ROLE}...)` is a subshell). Otherwise they are only available in the current context.